# Sorting function for keys in object with closure - Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, closures

I am creating an individual function for every key in the object like this:

**Object**

```
let users = [
  { name: "John", age: 20, surname: "Johnson" },
  { name: "Pete", age: 18, surname: "Peterson" },
  { name: "Ann", age: 19, surname: "Hathaway" }
];
```

**Simple sorting function**

```
// Sorting by name (Ann, John, Pete)
users.sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1);

// Sorting by age (Pete, Ann, John)
users.sort((a, b) => a.age > b.age ? 1 : -1);
```

It works well, but I need to create a dynamic function with closure, which will be called like this:

`users.sort(byField('name'));` instead of `users.sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1);`

**So far I tried this:**

```
function byField(str) {
  return (a, b) => a.str > b.str ? 1 : -1;
}

console.table(users.sort(byField('name')));
console.table(users.sort(byField('age')));
```

But it just returns the unsorted object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with brackets and a function which works kind of symmetrically and respects same values.

Read some more about functions which returns only a part, like `-1` and `1` or just a boolean value: [Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/)

```js
const withKey = key => (a, b) => (a[key] > b[key]) - (a[key] < b[key]);

let users = [{ name: "John", age: 20, surname: "Johnson" }, { name: "Pete", age: 18, surname: "Peterson" }, { name: "Ann", age: 19, surname: "Hathaway" }];

console.log(users.sort(withKey('name')));
console.log(users.sort(withKey('age')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That was awesome. Thank You for that article about sorting function. That was very interesting and helpful.